# How to write an msdeploy runcommand command that contains strings

Tags: command-line, command-prompt, msdeploy

Hi I'm trying to write an msdeploy command that contains two strings within the runcommand part of the command.

msdeploy.exe -verb:sync -source:runCommand="^"c:\opensesame\opensesame.cmd^" ^"c:\windows\system32^"" -dest:auto

I was trying to escape the quotes with the carats.

Basically what's suppose to happen is opensesame is called and the path is passed to it so it can open the calculator.

I'm guessing I don't have the right escape character?

Answer (score 1):

If `runCommand` is not given a full path (and only a full path) to a *bat* or *cmd* file, it will execute the command *as-is* on the server without uploading your *bat/cmd* file first. If you want to upload the script before executing it, you'll need to bake your parameters into the script and pass it without arguments to `runCommand`.